# how to generate the sql query using Easy Query builder in our project.?

Tags: asp.net, query-builder

I need to generate the sql query using the easy query builder i have added the required dll into my project this is my code ..

```
<keqwc:EntitiesPanel ID="EntitiesPanel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Entities and attributes"
    UseAppearanceStyle="False" ToolBarOnTop="False" UseDefaultStyle="False" Height="600px" Width="100%">
</keqwc:EntitiesPanel>

<keqwc:QueryColumnsPanel ID="QueryColumnsPanel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="none"
                                ToolTip="Result Columns" UseDefaultStyle="False"
                                UseAppearanceStyle="False"
                                Appearance-RowButtonTooltip="Click here to see all available operations" height="170px" Width="100%">
 </keqwc:QueryColumnsPanel>
 <keqwc:SortColumnsPanel ID="SortColumnsPanel1" runat="server" ToolTip="Columns Sorting" BorderStyle="none" UseDefaultStyle="False"
                                UseAppearanceStyle="False" Width="100%" height="170px">
                            </keqwc:SortColumnsPanel>
 <keqwc:QueryPanel ID="QueryPanel1" runat="server"
                            BorderStyle="none" ScrollBars="Auto"
                            Appearance-ScriptMenuStyle-ItemMinWidth="160"
                            UseListCache="True"
                            UseDefaultStyle="False" UseAppearanceStyle="False" Height="200px" Width="100%">
  </keqwc:QueryPanel>

<asp:TextBox ID="SqlTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="215px" width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in code behind i had added loaded the entity model using ..

```
private DbQuery query = null;
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    query = (DbQuery)Session["QUERY"];
    if (query == null)
    {
        string modelPath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\KorzhEasyQuery\\samples\\WebDemoAjaxCS\\App_Data\\NWindMDB.xml";

        Korzh.EasyQuery.DataModel model = new Korzh.EasyQuery.Db.DbModel();
        model.LoadFromFile(modelPath);

        query = new Korzh.EasyQuery.Db.DbQuery();
        query.Model = model;

        query.Formats.SetDefaultFormats(FormatType.MsSqlServer);
        Session["QUERY"] = query;
        QueryPanel1.Query = query;
        QueryColumnsPanel1.Query = QueryPanel1.Query;

        EntitiesPanel1.Query = QueryPanel1.Query;
        SortColumnsPanel1.Query = QueryPanel1.Query;


    }

}
```

i need to generate the sql query according to the specified condition, sorting order and columns how do i proceed with this..?

on click of add column and selecting the columns those selected columns are not displaying in the given query panel..

Comment: What is "easy query builder"?

Comment: A component library for .NET.
Just search for "Easy Query .NET" in Google.

Comment: @Gowthaman I just need to display the QueryPanel twice in the web page, but its getting displayed for the first time only. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move last 4 lines outside your "if" statement:

```
    if (query == null)
    {
     .  .  .  .  .     
    }
    QueryPanel1.Query = query;
    QueryColumnsPanel1.Query = QueryPanel1.Query;

    EntitiesPanel1.Query = QueryPanel1.Query;
    SortColumnsPanel1.Query = QueryPanel1.Query;
```

DbQuery and DbModel objects are initialized once per Session but your visual controls (QueryPanel, QueryColumnsPanel, etc) are re-created on each postback - so you should assign your DbQuery object on form load.